# Calculate the projected distance on an inclined plane

Tags: geometry

I have the following geometric drawing:

[image]

Given are:

- Points $P$ and $V$
- Vectors $\color{green}{\vec{r}}$, $\color{orange}{\vec{n}}$ and $\color{blue}{\vec{q}}$ (which are all normalized)
- Distance $|GH|$ between $G$ and $H$ (while $G$ and $H$ as such are not given)
- $V$ lies exactly in the middle between $G$ and $H$

I want to know the distance $|AB|$ between $\color{red}A$ and $\color{red}B$.

Normally I want to show you, what I've already done. But this time, I have a larger problem, and this is the part where I am stuck at. So unfortunately, the only thing, that I already calculated in this part is the distance $|PE|$, from the projection of $\vec{PV}$ along $\vec{r}$: $|PE| = \vec{PV} \cdot \vec{r}$.
But this didn't help me, so I am now asking here.

**Edit**:

I already thought of calculating the points $G = V + \frac{|GH|}{2} \cdot \color{blue}{\vec{q}}$, and $H = V - \frac{|GH|}{2} \cdot \color{blue}{\vec{q}}$.
Then I have the lines $\vec{PH}$ and $\vec{PG}$. I can intersect those lines with the substrate $\vec{s} = V + \lambda \cdot \vec{w}$ where $\vec{w} \bot \color{orange}{\vec{n}}$ to get the points $\color{red}A$ and $\color{red}B$.

But since I am not interested in neither $\color{red}A$ nor $\color{red}B$ I was wondering, if there is a simpler approach to just calculate the distance $|AB|$. So I would avoid the costs for calculating $\color{red}A$ and $\color{red}B$. My gut's telling me, that there has to be something like a trigonometric function of the angle between $\color{orange}{\vec{n}}$ and $\color{green}{\vec{r}}$. This would be much more efficient (I have to calculate the distance $|AB|$ many times in a program).

**Edit after help from gimusi:**
I can calculate the distance $|VB|$ with:
\begin{align}
    H &= V - \frac{|GH|}{2} \cdot \color{blue}{\vec{q}} \\
    \vec{HP} &= P - H \\
    \alpha = \angle PVB &= 90° - \arccos \left(\frac{\vec{VP}\cdot \vec{n}}{|\vec{VP}|} \right) \\
    \gamma &= \arccos \left(\frac{\color{blue}{\vec{q}} \cdot \vec{HP}}{|\vec{HP}|} \right)
\end{align}

Now I use the law of sine to calculate $\sin \delta$:
\begin{align}
    \frac{\sin \gamma}{|\vec{VP}|} &= \frac{\sin \delta}{|\vec{VH}|} \\
    \sin \delta &= \frac{|\vec{VH}|}{|\vec{VP}|} \cdot \sin \gamma
\end{align}

Now I know $\alpha$ and $\delta$, and with that $\beta = 180° - \alpha - \delta$.

With that I can use again the law of sine to calculate $|VB|$:

$$\frac{|VB|}{\sin \delta} = \frac{|VP|}{\sin \beta}$$

This gives me:
\begin{align}
    |VB| &= |VP| \cdot \frac{\sin \delta}{\sin \beta} \\
    |VB| &= |VP| \cdot \frac{\frac{|VH|}{|VP|} \cdot \sin \gamma}{\sin \beta} \\
     &= |VP| \cdot \frac{\frac{|VH|}{|VP|} \cdot \sin \left(\arccos\left(\frac{\vec{q} \cdot \vec{HP}}{|\vec{HP}|}\right)\right)}{\sin \left(180° - \left(90° - \arccos \left(\frac{\vec{VP} \cdot \vec{n}}{|\vec{VP}|}\right)\right) - \delta\right)} \\
     &= |VP| \cdot \frac{\frac{|VH|}{|VP|} \cdot \sin \left(\arccos\left(\frac{\vec{q} \cdot \vec{HP}}{|\vec{HP}|}\right)\right)}{\sin \left(180° - \left(90° - \arccos \left(\frac{\vec{VP} \cdot \vec{n}}{|\vec{VP}|}\right)\right) - \arcsin\left(\frac{|\vec{VH}|}{|\vec{VP}|} \cdot \sin \gamma \right) \right)} \\
     &= |VP| \cdot \frac{\frac{|VH|}{|VP|} \cdot \sin \left(\arccos\left(\frac{\vec{q} \cdot \vec{HP}}{|\vec{HP}|}\right)\right)}{\sin \left(180° - \left(90° - \arccos \left(\frac{\vec{VP} \cdot \vec{n}}{|\vec{VP}|}\right)\right) - \arcsin\left(\frac{|\vec{VH}|}{|\vec{VP}|} \cdot \sin \left( \arccos \left(\frac{\color{blue}{\vec{q}} \cdot \vec{HP}}{|\vec{HP}|} \right) \right) \right) \right)}
\end{align}

I am not sure, if this is quite correct?

Comment: $\sin(\arccos x)=\sqrt(1-x^2)$. I haven’t check through this, but beware of sign ambiguities introduced by using the cosines of angles.

Comment: I’m a bit puzzled by this. You say that you want to avoid the “expense” of explicitly computing the projections of the two points, which at worst requires five cross products and four divisions, (plus the distance computation, of course), but take an approach that involves much more expensive trig and inverse trig functions. Which parts of this setup are fixed over the many times that you have to calculate $|AB|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

- write parametric line VB: $V+t\vec w \quad \vec w\perp \vec n$
- find H by $V- \frac{|GH|}2 \vec q$
- write parametric  line PH
- intersect the two lines to find B

**Update after editing**

As an alternative

- find angles $\alpha=\angle PVB$ and $\beta=\angle VBP$
- apply law of sines to $\triangle PVB\implies \frac{PB}{\sin \alpha}=\frac{PV}{\sin \beta}$

Comment: Yeah, I already thought of calculating lines and intersect them (I should have added this to the question), but I was wondering, if there is a simpler approach. My gut's telling me, that there has to be something like a trigonometric function of the angle between $\color{orange}{\vec{n}}$ and $\color{green}{\vec{r}}$. This would be much more efficient (I have to calculate this many times in a program).

Comment: @Rico-E Yes as an alternative we can find some angles and apply law of sines

Comment: I would appreciate it very much, if you could lead me to this alternative.

Comment: @Rico-E I've updated, can you find the angles? you need to use dot product

Comment: @Rico-E Once you have tha angles you are done indeed $$\frac{PB}{\sin \alpha}=\frac{PV}{\sin \beta}\implies PB= \frac{PV}{\sin \beta}{\sin \alpha} $$

Comment: Yes, I just realized it by myself, so I deleted my comment :)

Comment: @Rico-E Well done!

Comment: No, sorry. I'm not done. What I can, is $\alpha = 90° - \arccos\left(\frac{\vec{PV} \cdot \color{orange}{\vec{n}}}{|\vec{PV}|}\right)$. But I am again stuck at calculating $\beta = \angle VBP$. I thought I can use the triangle $VPH$, where I know two sides ($VP$ and $VH$) and the angle between these sides. This should be enough to calculate the rest, but I do not know how.

Comment: @Rico-E You can find H by the previous hint and then the vector PH

Comment: I just finished calculating $|VB|$ (I have edited the question). Would you be so kind, to have a look, if this is correct?

Comment: @Rico-E Firstly note that for the calculaton of $\alpha$ is $PV=V-P$ you are evaluation the complement, it is not a problem for the final answer since $\sin (\pi-\alpha)=\sin(\alpha)$. The same consideration can be done also for $\gamma$.

Comment: @Rico-E Your derivation is quite complicated, you can make it more simple!

Comment: @Rico-E You already have $\alpha$, now calculate $\beta=90°+\arccos \left(\frac{\vec{n} \cdot \vec{HP}}{|\vec{HP}|} \right)$ and then  $$ \frac{|PB|}{\sin \alpha}=\frac{|PV|}{\sin \beta} \implies |PB=\frac{|PV|}{\sin \beta}|{\sin \alpha}$$